# I can't find nsight eclipse and cuda samples after installing CUDA5.0 on my macbook pro

Tags: macos, cuda, installation

I'm a student who starts to learn CUDA programming. But I can't install the CUDA toolkit on my macbook pro retina 15 successfully . I've checked the installing instruction, and I have installed the gcc from Xcode. However, it only took me about 1 minute to install cuda_5.0.36_macos.pkg which not seems like reasonable. In fact, I can't find the nsight eclipse and other softwares , and there is no sample in ./Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.0/.  It's my first time to use OS X and I don't  know how to solve the problem now.

Comment: you should install it with root privilage. not sure how to do that on mac.

Comment: did you follow the instructions [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-mac-os-x/index.html) ?  what happens if you type `nsight` at a command prompt?

Comment: I installed it follow that instructions,and the bash show command not find

Comment: What were the results of the "Verify the Installation" process?   For example, for verify the driver installation, what was the result there (`kextstat | grep -i cuda`)? Have you set the PATH and DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH variables?  You may also need to capture the output from the installer process and paste it in here, and also check the installer logs in /var/log

Comment: @SorooshBateni CUDA toolkit installer will request all necessary permissions - there's nothing special the user should do.

Comment: Can you use nvcc or cuda-gdb? Did you have previous CUDA Toolkit installed? Make sure you don't have older toolkit on your path. Note that install may actually be that fast on SSD-equiped laptop.

Comment: Boy he has a lot of questions to answer :D. you guys are awesome!

Answer (score 1):

The path is `/Developer/NVIDIA` and not `./Developer/NVIDIA`. After installation the path to the bin folder is not set, thus terminal does not find it. But you find nsight in the bin folder at `/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-x.y/bin`